# Running windows 7 C++ exe on windows server 2008

Tags: php, c++, windows-7, coldfusion, windows-server-2008

I have a C++ code that needs to be used in a web application using ColdFusion or PHP. For that I was trying to get an idea of running exe through Coldfusion/PHP scripts, but my exe compiled on my computer are not running on server.

Does a C++ code compiled on windows 7 run on Windows Server 2008 enterprise edition? or do i have to compile code on windows server again?

Thanks in advance. :)

**Answer**: thanks for the rplies....i found out it was not working because "cfexecute" tag i was using to run c++ exe, is not allowed on web server, that is why the code was not returning any output.

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, in general it should work.  What error do you get when trying to run the exe on the server?  Do you have the right C runtime installed on the server?

Comment: *"[does] not run"* is not an error description. Please provide detailed information. Are there any error messages when you start the application? Does it start up and then fail? There is no relation between the build machine and the target machine: You can build a WinRT application targetting an ARM CPU on a 32bit Intel XP machine, for example.

Comment: @user2318281 - If you solved the issue, you should write it up as an "answer", so it is more visible.